# MySQL Update after some content

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I am currently making some updates to a table on my DB. The idea is simple, I want to put some "content" after some "content".

I this case I have a column "posts_content" on the table "posts" with this example content:

```
<h1>TEXT....</h1>
<p>TEXT....</p>
<h2>TEXT....</h2>
<p>TEXT....</p>
<h2>TEXT....</h2>
<p>SOME TEXT WITH A SQL QUERY.....</p>
```

I want to put some text after the second "".

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer!!

But the problem with that is that the content continues, I put a the first part only as example, my bad. Please imagine something like this:

```
<h1>TEXT....</h1>

<p>TEXT....</p>

<h2>TEXT....</h2>

<p>TEXT....</p>

<h2>TEXT....</h2>

<p>SOME TEXT WITH A SQL QUERY.....</p>

<p>TEXT....</p>

<h2>TEXT....</h2>    

<p>TEXT....</p>
```

I want tu put the text after the second `</h2>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "id" column of your table is called "ID" and pretending that the id of the post in question is, say, 3:

`UPDATE posts SET posts_content = CONCAT(posts_content, '<p>SOME TEXT WITH A SQL QUERY.....</p>') WHERE ID = 3`